# Writing a paragraph, then new line, then normal text in LyX

Tags: lyx

I have a paragraph written, then I inserted a new line using CONTROL+SHIFT+RETURN, and after that new line I'm trying to write using the normal style, but it gets autoconverted to paragraph style, how can I avoid this and keep both of the styles?

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand what you did, but presumably you want to hit just Enter, not Ctrl+Shift+Enter. In general, at the end of headings like Paragraph, Section etc., hit enter to exit the heading style and go back to normal text.

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` insert a `\linebreak` in LaTeX code. That start a new line **in the same paragraph**, so without indentation nor vertical skip. To start a new paragraph (with or without indentation, with or without vertical skip), as commented above, is just Enter, that insert a blank line (=`\par`) in LaTeX. Open the Code Pane to see that are you doing really in LaTeX  with every the LyX command.